# How to find element of the below HTML?

Tags: selenium

Am curious if anyone might know which Selenium locating element method would be used to identify the below html.

I am trying to locate and 'click'

```
button type="submit" tabindex="3" data-ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" data-ng-class="{ 'gray': loginForm.$invalid }">Login</button
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you know text is not gonna change, direct use text

```
//button[text()='Login']
```

or based on attributes

```
//button[@data-ng-click='login()']
```

You can combine these two like below :

```
//button[@data-ng-click='login()' and text()='Login']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 0):

You can following xpath,

1. //button[@type='submit']
2. //button[@data-ng-click='login()']
3. //button[text()='login']

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='X']")).click();